# Error occurred upon executing query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I was trying to update my website content by a pop up window. I made the content appear according to the ID but when I try to submit it an error appears on the pop up

> An error occurred upon executing query.
>   Please notify the web developer about this error.
>
> NOTE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE textID=16' at line 1

and I can't seem to find the bug.  Can you see it?

Here's my complete code:

```
    <!-- PHP -->
<?
    include('global.php');

    if(isset($_REQUEST['textID']))
        $textID = $_REQUEST['textID'];      
    if(isset($_REQUEST['textContent']))
        $textContent = $_REQUEST['textContent'];

            if($_POST){
            $query = "UPDATE text_tb SET ";
            $query = $query."textContent='".$textContent."', ";
            $query = $query."WHERE textID=".$textID.""; 
            //echo $query;
            ExecuteQuery($query);
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                <!--
                window.close();
                //-->
                </script>";
            }
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Full featured example</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,visualblocks",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,forecolor",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->

</head>
<body role="application">

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <div>
                <!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
        <div>
            <textarea id="textContent" name="textContent" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
            <?
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM text_tb WHERE textID ='".$textID."'");
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                    echo $row['textContent'];
                                }
            ?>
            </textarea>
        </div>

        <!-- Some integration calls
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.get('textContent').show();return false;">[Show]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.get('textContent').hide();return false;">[Hide]</a>-->
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.location.protocol == 'file:') {
    alert("The examples might not work properly on the local file system due to security settings in your browser. Please use a real webserver.");
}
</script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beware [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the comma at the end of the set.  Change this line:

```
        $query = $query."textContent='".$textContent."', ";
```

to:

```
        $query = $query."textContent='".$textContent."' ";
```

Comment: little mistake I made there. thanks a lot!